WiFiDog Gateway Implementation on a VM
I am working on WiFiDog Authentication for Ruijie AP and I need to setup a NAS which will work as gateway between AP and Auth Server (Using WiFiDog Auth Laravel Github repo).
Can anyone please help/guide me how to achieve this. I want to host a VM on the same subnet as my Ruijie AP.
Much appreciated.
I have tried to assign nas-ip to Ruijie AP and there is no way to check the log of requests made or how authentication is working. I can't check logs if nas-ip is set to Ruijie AP IP. I want to setup a NAS VM server.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have a Ruijie AP (Model: 820-L (V2)) for which I need to enable WiFiDog Auth.

I have a Ruijie AP (Model: 820-L (V2)) for which I need to enable WiFiDog Auth.
I am using this repo for WiFiDog Auth Server:
https://github.com/wifidog/wifidog-auth-laravel
When I connect to WiFi SSID, internet is blocked and only opened once authentication is completed via Auth Server but I am unable to disconnect internet even after I logout from Auth server. I am also unable to set session timeout, download and upload rate for any authenticated user.
I don't know how to setup a WiFiDog Gateway between AP and client (end user).
Do I need to add more information?
